# How do I allow Multi-line content in a rails text_area field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I go about allowing users to input multi-line text in a `text_area` form field?

Currently anytime content is entered in the `text area`the line breaks are removed... They are retained when I edit the content... So, maybe it's in the show view that the breaks are being removed?

I've found a few things that indicate that I'd need to implement a WYSIWYG editor, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** So, it looks like rails saves the content with line breaks, and I can add `.html_safe` to the field in the show view (i.e. `<%= @post.post.html_safe %>`). Now it will present content with basic html (e.g. `<br>`, `<b>`, etc...) but still doesn't present the line breaks in the content (i.e. when I press enter for a new line) that are saved by rails and I can view when I'm editing the content.

Comment: A textarea has nothing Rails specific. Html is html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Linebreaks are not rendered in HTML. You will want to use something like [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) or [wraptext](https://github.com/cheald/wraptext) on your content as you echo it out to convert newlines to `<br>` or `<p>` tags.

```
<%=simple_format(@post.post).html_safe %>
```

or

```
<%=Wraptext::Parser.new(@post.post).to_html.html_safe %>
```

Comment: `simple_format` has `:sanitize` enabled by default, so `.html_safe` is redundant.

Comment: Great, `simple_format` and `html_safe` are exactly what I am looking for, thanks Chris.